# To increase the home directory

Tags: home-directory

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 and I have installed redmine service for users who are working in php and testing. While they are using it, some of them are getting "internal server error".

Actually my home directory space is too small when I checked the properties of redmine. It shows me as 0kB after cleaning cache by typing `sudo apt-get autoclean & sudo apt-get clean`.

After that size of the directory increase to 20MB but it is not sufficient for 15 users.

My question is do, I need to increase /home directory size? Is it possible to do it? What are the ways to do that without losing data?

Answer (score 0):

On your first question, yes, you may need to increase your /home directory size.

Does your hard drive has an unallocated space or is it being used by another mount point (e.g. /, /home, /swap)?

If you are doing this on a live box, please backup your files just in case.

Provided that all of the backups are taken care of, you may want to install GParted if it is not yet installed. Then you may want to use any unallocated space to expand your /home partition OR shrink your / or /swap partitions and expand your /home partition.

Comment: And also I am using dual os I have given only 6gb to ubuntu is that possible to use gparted software to resize the home directory from other drive ?

Comment: if you are using windows, right click My Computer > Manage then look for the Hard Drives. From Windows Vista to Windows 8, you can resize vritual paritions from the gui. Then continue with gparted.